# A different objective function in liner regression analysis

Tags: st.statistics, linear-regression, estimation-theory

I'm an undergraduate student who is green in statistics. I have a problem in the chose of objective function when estimating the parameters.

Let $Y = \beta^TX + \epsilon $ be the standard liner regression model, where $Y$ is the response, $X$ the $p$-dimensional covariate vector with $\beta$ the corresponding regression parameter vector and $\epsilon$ the error term that is independent of covariate. And let $Y_i$, $X_i$, $i = 1, 2, ..., n$, be the observations.

Some authors define an objective function as
$$
U_n(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|e_i(\beta)-e_j(\beta)|, 
$$
where $e_i(\beta) = Y_i - \beta^TX_i$, the residual of $i$th observation.

Like OLS, $\hat\beta$, the fitting value of $\beta$, is the minimiser of the objective function $U_n(\beta)$. In OLS method, the meaning of objective function is clear. It is the sum of "absolute errors" (absolute values of residuals).

But **what's the meaning of $U_n(\beta)$ here, and why authors choose this function**?

Comment: A link or a reference would help

Comment: The integration of the so called Mann-Whitney-type estimating equation is $U_n(\beta)$. (p5, Z. Ying, W. Yu, Z. Zhao, M. Zheng, _Regression analysis of doubly truncated data_, _preprint_, [link]http://https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00902)

Comment: That paper suggests that it is considering a variant of a minimand from a 2001 paper (http://www.columbia.edu/~zj7/resampling.pdf), so the answer should be in that 2001 paper....but I can't actually see the connection between the two papers.  In any case, the scientific motivation seems to be the double truncation of quasar data:  quasars too dim can't be observed well, and quasars too bright look too much like other objects.